# Linq to Sql Criteria in String Array

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have say three tables.

Projects

- Id
- Name

Categories

- Id
- Name

ProjectCategories

- Id
- ProjectId
- CategoryId

I now have an array of strings which represents categories the user has elected to search on.  I now need to find all the projects that have those category attached to them.

I tried;

```
string[] searchTerms = new string[2];
searchTerms[0] = "paint";
searchTerms[1] = "painting";

IQueryable<Project> projects = (from category in dc.ProjectCategories
where searchTerms.Any(val => category.Category.Name.Contains(val))
select category.Project).Distinct();
```

But I get the error;

{"Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementation of query operators except the Contains() operator."}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm mistaking your meaning, which is possible, I think you can just do a contains with the searchTerms

```
where searchTerms.Contains( category.Category.Name )
```

this will translate into SQL as

```
... WHERE Name IN ('paint','painting') ...
```

Comment: Argh!  So easy when you see it.  Thanks @tv.